# Select from one table if present in that table or another one

Tags: mysql

I have two tables. When the user start typing in a searchbox, code select matchig term from two tables and retrieve data from the first one.
As an example:

**Table A** (movies data)

| Movie_code | Movie_Name | Company |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABx1 | Love in Umbria | Paramount |
| TR55 | Whales and dolphins | Metro |
| HG2 | In the beginning | Paramount |
| YU9 | Afterglow | Columbia |

**Table B** (actors)

| Movie_code | Actor_Name |
| --- | --- |
| ABx1 | Tom Hanks |
| ABx1 | Isabelle Huppert |
| ABx1 | Ralph Fiennes |
| ABx1 | Marcello Mastroianni |
| TR55 | Clint Eastwood |
| TR55 | Mia Farrow |
| TR55 | Isabelle Huppert |

I know how to search in one table:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TableA 
WHERE Movie_code LIKE ? OR Movie_Name LIKE ? OR Company LIKE ?
```

and then binding the parameter `%SearchTerm%`. For "Metro" I would get one result, for "Paramount" I wil get two results, and for "um" there will be two results (the first movie, Love in Umbria, and the last one, for the company name, Columbia).

I have tried a `LEFT JOIN` for searching in the two tables:

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM TableA a 
LEFT JOIN TableB b ON a.Movie_code=b.Movie_code 
WHERE a.Movie_code LIKE ? OR a.Movie_Name LIKE ? OR a.Company LIKE ? 
OR b.Actor_Name LIKE ?
```

My problem is that for a single letter (say "a") the code finds many results in Table B (actors), **resulting in a repetition of movies**. Entering letter "a" should retrieve only the four movies, "Huppert" should return two results, "Afterglow" only one, and so on.

Any ideas?

Comment: You only want to search the actors if there are no matches in movies? Then you should do it as separate queries -- first query movies, if no results are found, do the joined query to find matching actors.

Comment: I want to search altoghter. For example searching "nn" should display the movies "In the beginning" (has nn) and "Love in Umbria" (since Ralph Fiennes -nn- is an actor in that movie)

Comment: Use `SELECT DISTINCT a.*` to get rid of the duplicates.

Comment: Thats it!! `SELECT DISTINCT `. Easy, thanks!